# choosing cabin type on /v2/offers/shop

Tags: sabre, sabredav

can someone help me? I am looking for a method to get all kind of cabin type of Sabre on /v2/offers/shop request at the same time in all itineraries. Below is my code. please answer with a full JSON. any help is valuable. another problem is where can I find some good examples for NDC and non-NDC for  /v2/offers/shop?

```
{
    "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
        "OriginDestinationInformation": [
            {
                "DepartureDateTime": "2020-06-21T00:00:00",
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "YYC"
                },
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "YYZ"
                },
                "RPH": "0"
            },
            {
                "DepartureDateTime": "2020-06-25T00:00:00",
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "YYZ"
                },
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "YYC"
                },
                "RPH": "1"
            }
        ],
        "POS": {
            "Source": [
                {
                    "PseudoCityCode": "xxxxxxx",
                    "RequestorID": {
                        "CompanyName": {
                            "Code": "xxxxxxxxxx"
                        },
                        "ID": "1",
                        "Type": "1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "TPA_Extensions": {
            "IntelliSellTransaction": {
                "RequestType": {
                    "Name": "xxxxxxx"
                }
            }
        },
        "TravelPreferences": {
            "TPA_Extensions": {
                "DataSources": {
                    "ATPCO": "Enable",
                    "LCC": "Enable",
                    "NDC": "Enable"
                },
                "NumTrips": {},
                "FlexibleFares": {
                    "FareParameters": [
                        {
                            "PassengerType": {
                                "Code": "ADT"
                            },
                            "Cabin": {
                                "Type": "Y"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "PassengerType": {
                                "Code": "ADT"
                            },
                            "Cabin": {
                                "Type": "S"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "PassengerType": {
                                "Code": "ADT"
                            },
                            "Cabin": {
                                "Type": "C"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "TravelerInfoSummary": {
            "AirTravelerAvail": [
                {
                    "PassengerTypeQuantity": [
                        {
                            "Code": "ADT",
                            "Quantity": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "Code": "CNN",
                            "Quantity": 2
                        },
                        {
                            "Code": "INF",
                            "Quantity": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "SeatsRequested": [
                5
            ]
        },
        "Version": "1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, not sure about cabins, but you can take a look into Sabre APIs and NDC here
https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/postman-collections

https://github.com/SabreDevStudio

Comment: thx. I have checked all before. there is nothing for cabin selection.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get all kind of cabin type response in a single request, 
you have to search differently for each cabin type,
here are the cabin types if you need them:

> 1. Premium First (P),
> 2. First (F),
> 3. Premium Business (J),
> 4. Business (C),
> 5. Premium Economy (S)
> 6. Economy (Y)

but you can search different flights with different cabin type in a single itinerary in the **OriginDestinationInformation** block

```
"OriginDestinationInformation": [
      {
        "DepartureDateTime": "2019-06-21T00:00:00",
        "DestinationLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "LAX"
        },
        "OriginLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "NYC"
        },
        "TPA_Extensions": {
            "CabinPref": {
              "Cabin": "Y"
            }
        },
        "RPH": "0"
      },
      {
        "DepartureDateTime": "2019-06-22T00:00:00",
        "DestinationLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "NYC"
        },
        "OriginLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "LAX"
        },
        "TPA_Extensions": {
            "CabinPref": {
              "Cabin": "C"
            }
        },
        "RPH": "1"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for different flights with different cabin types in a single itinerary in the OriginDestinationInformation block of the OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ request.

You can use the  Cabin Pref option to specify preferred cabin to be used in a search for this leg level (if SegmentType is "O") or segment (if SegmentType is "X").

The cabin type specified in this element will override the cabin type specified at the request level for this leg/segment.

- If a cabin type is not specified for this element the cabin type at request level will be used as a default for this leg or segment.
- If the cabin type is not specified at both the leg/segment level and request level a default cabin of "Economy" will be used.

Here is a sample:-

```
"OriginDestinationInformation": [
  {
    "DepartureDateTime": "2020-07-05T00:00:00",
    "DestinationLocation": {
      "LocationCode": "SFO"
    },
    "OriginLocation": {
      "LocationCode": "NYC"
    },
    "TPA_Extensions": {
        "CabinPref": {
          "Cabin": "Y"
        }
    },
    "RPH": "0"`},
  {
    "DepartureDateTime": "2020-07-10T00:00:00",
    "DestinationLocation": {
      "LocationCode": "NYC"
    },
    "OriginLocation": {
      "LocationCode": "SFO"
    },
    "TPA_Extensions": {
        "CabinPref": {
          "Cabin": "C"
        }
    },
    "RPH": "1"
  }
]
```

`
Here is a link that provides details of NDC in Sabre:-
https://developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/services/NDC